# How can I stop timer with sensor?

Tags: android

I have a condition, and I handle it via if block. But in otherwise timer must stop. I try it but there is not working. My goal, when phone is horizontal line(last_z >= -1.5 && last_z <= 1.5) application will start timer. There is not problem so far. But when horizontal angle fails timer must stop. I can't do it via else because when I write else loop, timer not resolved?

```
if (last_z >= -1.5 && last_z <= 1.5 && dongu){
          eksenx.setText("3, 2, 1 ready...");

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                            Intent hazirlik = new Intent(hazirlikekrani.this,internetsiteleri.class);
                            startActivity(hazirlik);
                            System.exit(0);


                        }

                });
                }

            };

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 3000);   
              vibrator.vibrate(500);
              dongu = false; 

              if (last_z < -1.5 && last_z > 1.5) {

                  eksenx.setText("again align"); //text verisi degistirildi
                  timer.cancel();


              }

      } if (last_z > 9){
        dongu = true;
      }
```